# Initialisation of static vector

Tags: c++, static-members, stdvector

I wonder if there is the "nicer" way of initialising a static vector than below?

```
class Foo
{
    static std::vector<int> MyVector;
    Foo()
    {
        if (MyVector.empty())
        {
            MyVector.push_back(4);
            MyVector.push_back(17);
            MyVector.push_back(20);
        }
    }
}
```

It's an example code :)

The values in push_back() are declared independly; not in array or something.

Edit: if it isn't possible, tell me that also :)

Comment: Would be interested to see what the C++0x folks will say. I think something like Foo::MyVector {4,17,20} outside the class definition is possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Typically, I have a class for constructing containers that I use (like [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) from boost), such that you can do:

```
const list<int> primes = list_of(2)(3)(5)(7)(11);
```

That way, you can make the static const as well, to avoid accidental modifications.

For a static, you could define this in the .cc file:

```
// Foo.h

class Foo {
  static const vector<int> something;
}

// Foo.cc

const vector<int> Foo::something = list_of(3)(5);
```

In C++Ox, we'll have a language mechanism to do this, using initializer lists, so you could just do:

```
const vector<int> primes({2, 3, 5, 7, 11});
```

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists).

Comment: I guess if he emphasises that the values are "not in an array", then the new feature won't do much good either. I guess there's no way around either getting them into some sort of collection or live with the repeated insertion calls.

Comment: I think list_of is what I need. It looks simple and, I think, faster than multiple push_backs. When I said "they are not in array", I didn't mention that they can't be in one.

Comment: Most likely, it is internally using multiple push_back()s, so it isn't "faster" in that sense. It does avoid a conditional in the constructor, which would make that faster. However, static initialization is probably not where your code spends majority of time, so optimizing those sections will most likely not be a noticeable gain gain.

Answer (score 56):

In C++03, the easiest way was to use a factory function:

```
std::vector<int> MakeVector()
{
    std::vector v;
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(17);
    v.push_back(20);
    return v;
}

std::vector Foo::MyVector = MakeVector(); // can be const if you like
```

"Return value optimisation" should mean that the array is filled in place, and not copied, if that is a concern. Alternatively, you could initialise from an array:

```
int a[] = {4,17,20};
std::vector Foo::MyVector(a, a + (sizeof a / sizeof a[0]));
```

If you don't mind using a non-standard library, you can use Boost.Assignment:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

std::vector Foo::MyVector = boost::list_of(4,17,20);
```

In C++11 or later, you can use brace-initialisation:

```
std::vector Foo::MyVector = {4,17,20};
```

Comment: +1 for new language features (uniform initialization syntax ftw).

Comment: This function is bad idea because there will be only one static vector to fill.

Comment: @Xirdus: What makes it a bad idea? If you need to initialise a non-empty array, then that's one way to do it.

Comment: I asked for something what will shorten and clear the code. The above code (in my certain case) is as useful as #define MyMain main(int argc, char** argv)

Comment: @Xirdus: No, you asked for a "nicer" way to initialise a vector. My answer gives a way of actually initialising it (rather than populating an array that was initialised empty), which allows you (for example) to initialise a constant vector. So it does answer what you asked, if not what you thought you meant.

Answer (score 30):

With C++11:

```
//The static keyword is only used with the declaration of a static member, 
//inside the class definition, not with the definition of that static member:
std::vector<int> Foo::MyVector = {4, 17, 20};
```

Comment: Hi this is giving me : error: qualified-id in declaration before '=' token. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
MyVector.insert(MyVector.begin(), arr, &arr[sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(*arr)]);
```

But it's probably only worth when you have a really long vector, and it doesn't look much nicer, either. However, you get rid of the repeated push_back() calls. Of course, if your values are "not in an array" you'd have to put them into there first, but you'd be able to do that statically (or at least references/pointers), depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

How about initializing using a static object.  In its constuctor it
could call a static function in the object to do the initalization.

Comment: Please elaborate or give an example.

Comment: create a class declaration with only a constructor, wherein you push_back a value (or multiple values) into the global/static vector. Then create a static instance of that class -> the constructor will get called before main, and the static vector will be populated. The instance wont pose any memory overhead as it doesnt contain any member variables. (use an unnamed namespace in your cpp file to declare/define/instantiate the helper class)

Answer (score 0):

with boost you can use the +=() operator defined in the boost::assign namespace.

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>

using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
    static std::vector<int> MyVector;
    MyVector += 4,17,20;
    return 0;
}
```

or with static initialization:

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>

using namespace boost::assign;

static std::vector<int> myVector = list_of(4)(17)(2);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

or even better, if your compiler supports C++ 11, use initialization lists.

Comment: Can I do this `static` class members?

Comment: C++ 11 has initialization lists for this, or you could use structures instead of classes and statically initialize them MyStruct val = {1, 2, 3 }. Otherwise, for private class members, you'd have to use a constructor.