# c++ static member, how do I test it

Tags: c++, static

I have a class in foo.h containing a static member

```
class foo {
 public:
  static vector<int> a;
  static void Init() { // Init a }
}
```

Everything works fine until I have a testing file
foo_test.cpp which is testing class foo. But in the
testing file, the static member a is not visible because
static member is only visible... How do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give your `foo_test.cpp` so we can see what you mean? Don't forget to define `a`. You can initialize it to 0 in the definition and get rid of the need for the user to call `Init` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to define `a`, in your `cpp` file add a line like:

```
vector<int> foo::a;
```

**Edit:** changed the data type to reflect the edit in the question

Comment: Can I callfoo::Init() instead?

Comment: no, you need to `define` the variable like in the code I provided

Comment: what if it's a vector not a int?

Comment: you will still need to declare you vector using something like `std::vector foo::myvector;`

Comment: did you add it to your CPP file like suggested?

Comment: Yes, I did... it's a vector not a int. If I do std::vector<int> foo::a, then it will be recognized as a declare, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do in your cpp

Comment: Oh, it works :) I put it in the main function previously, that's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you call foo::Init() outside the scope, you will get function re-declaration error. If you put it inside the scope, you will getting unresolved external symbol. You can only init it as int foo::a = 0;

Comment: Sorry, a is actuallyl a vector, how do I init it then? If I do vector<int> foo::a  it won't work...

Comment: You can also refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701903/initialisation-of-static-vector