# How to create a vector<string> or similar without pushing?

Tags: c++, list, vector

I need to create a `vector<vector<string>>` and for each `vector<string>` in `vector` I need to have a few characters inside like `new vector<string>("a","A","á");`.

But I don't want to `push_back` every character. Is there a way to do it like I did there?

Comment: If you know the strings for each vector at compile time, you can use initializer lists (assuming C++11)

Comment: Possibly related (although not nominating to close as a duplicate as you might be using C++11): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c03-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701903/initialisation-of-static-vector

Answer (score 3):

**C++11**

`std::vector` has an `insert` member-function that accepts a `std::initializer_list` in **C++11**, as well as a constructor which also accepts a `std::initializer_list`.

With this in mind we can easily write code that inserts more than one element without individual push_backs, nor do we have to manually construct a temporary container that the insert function can iterate over.

---

```
// construct `multi_vec` and initialize it with one std::vector<std::string>,
// having the elements "hello", "stackoverflow", and "world"

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> multi_vec {
   { "hello", "stackoverflow", "world" }
};

// resize, to add another (empty) std::vector<std::string> to `multi_vec`

multi_vec.resize (2); 

// insert some elements to `multi_vec[1]`

multi_vec[1].insert (multi_vec[1].end (), { "foo", "bar", "baz", "caz" });
```

```
multi_vec[0] -> { "hello", "stackoverflow", "world" } 
multi_vec[1] -> { "foo", "bar", "baz", "caz" }
```

<sup>**Note:** The first argument to the relevant `insert` *member-function* of `std::vector` accepts an iterator specifying the element after in which the new elements should be inserted, passing `our_vec.end ()` will append our elements to the end of our list.</sup>

---

---

**C++03**

Things has to be done in a more ugly manner if one doesn't write **C++11** but instead is using **C++03**, below is a simple example with the same result as the example in the previous section.

```
char const * init_array_1[] = { "hello", "stackoverflow", "world" };
char const * init_array_2[] = { "foo", "bar", "baz", "caz" };

std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > multi_vec;

multi_vec.push_back (std::vector<std::string> (init_array_1, init_array_1 + 3));
multi_vec.push_back (std::vector<std::string> (init_array_2, init_array_2 + 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

In c++11, you can do:

```
vector<vector<string>> v{
    {"A", "á", "á"},
    // more vectors...
};
```

Comment: `char` is a single byte, accented characters might be multi-bytes, so actually `std::string` is a much safer choice.

Comment: Good point. I removed the comment suggesting `char` vectors. `wchar_t`  might be useful in this case.

Comment: `wchar_t` is useless, because it's platform dependent. Using Visual Studio this means a 16-bits integer which is insufficient for part of the Unicode Code Points.

Comment: According to standard, "Type wchar_t is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest
extended character set specified among the supported locales
". Considering that, does MSVC only supports locales with maximum of 16 bit character sets?

Comment: According to which version of the Standard ? FYI C++11 introduces `char16_t` and `char32_t` to solve the portability issues.

Comment: According to c++11 (draft n3242).

Comment: @user2079303: I think so; their MultiByte locales were limited to ASCII plus 2 byte extensions (i.e. 128+32768) so their 16 bit `wchar_t` choice can hold any valid converted multi-byte character. UTF-8 is not supported in MSVC locales and thus there's no need for a 20+ bit `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<vector<string>> v;

v.push_back(vector<string> { "A", "á", "à" });
```

Comment: And im not using c++11