# how to initialise a static member variable container with elements that are instances of structs?

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello so I have a class that uses 5 instances of a struct and I would like a static vector to hold those instances but I do not want the elements themselves to be static.

the header file looks like this

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


struct table {
    unsigned int tableNumber;
    unsigned int numChairs;
    unsigned int numberOfPeople;
    bool occupied;

    //table();

    void toggleOccupied() {
        if (occupied == true) {
            occupied = false;
        }
        else
        {
            occupied = true;
        }
    }

    bool getTableOccupied() {
        return occupied;
    }

    void setNumChairs(int newChairNum) {
        numChairs = newChairNum;
    }

    void setTableNumber(int assignTableNum) {
        tableNumber = assignTableNum;
    }

     int getTablenumber() {
        return tableNumber;
    }

     int getNumberOfChairs() {
        return numChairs;
    }

    void setNumberOfPeople(int addNumPeople) {
        numberOfPeople = addNumPeople;
    }


};





class tableOrder {
public:

    tableOrder();
    
    int getSP() {
        return SP;
    }

    enum ServingProgress {
        seated,
        drinksOrder,
        starters,
        main,
        dessert,
        bill
    };

    ServingProgress SP = seated;

    std::string progress;

    void getCurrentProgress() {
        switch (SP) {
        case 0:
            progress = "seated";
            break;
        case 1:
            progress = "drinksOrder";
            break;
        case 2:
            progress = "starters";
            break;
        case 3:
            progress = "main";
            break;
        case 4:
            progress = "dessert";
            break;
        case 5:
            progress = "bill";
            break;
        }
    }

    void ProgressOrder() {
        switch (SP) {
        case 0:
            SP = drinksOrder;
            break;
        case 1:
            SP = starters;
            break;
        case 2:
            SP = main;
            break;
        case 3:
            SP = dessert;
            break;
        case 4:
            SP = dessert;
            break;
        case 5:
            SP = bill;
            progress = "finished";
            break;
        }
    }

    void checkForTablesInUse() {
        for (int i(0); i < allTables.size(); i++) {
            if (allTables[i].occupied) {
                TablesInUse.push_back(allTables[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    void checkForTablesNotInUse() {
        for (int i(0); i < TablesInUse.size(); i++) {
            if (TablesInUse[i].occupied == false) {
                TablesInUse.erase(TablesInUse.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }

    void updateTablesInUse() {
        checkForTablesInUse();
        checkForTablesNotInUse();
    }

    table& getTable(unsigned int tableIndex) {
        return allTables[tableIndex - 1];
    }

    //instantiate tables
    table table_1 = { 1,6,0,false };
    table table_2 = { 2,5,0,false };
    table table_3 = { 3,4,0,false };
    table table_4 = { 4,8,0,false };
    table table_5 = { 5,4,0,false };


//protected:

    unsigned int assignedTableNumber;

    table assignedTable;

    static vector<table> availableTables;
    static vector<table> TablesInUse;
    static vector<table> TablesToSelect;
    static vector<table>  allTables;
    static tableOrder passTable;

};
```

I have made 5 instance of table and want to store them in the static allTables.
Here is the cpp file

```
#include "TableOrder.h"

vector<table> tableOrder::availableTables = {};
vector<table> tableOrder::TablesInUse = {};
vector<table> tableOrder::TablesToSelect = {};
vector<table>tableOrder::allTables = {table_1,table_2,table_3,table_4,table_5 };

tableOrder::tableOrder() {
     assignedTableNumber = 0;

     assignedTable = table_1;
    
     
     
}
```

I understand why I can't initialise allTables like this as I am putting unique variables inside a shared variable. Is there any decent way around this?
thanks for the help!

Comment: You can simplify your code quite a bit. Simple getters and setters make zero sense in a `struct` where the data is already public. The getters were also not written to best practices as they weren't marked `const`.

Comment: As to your actual question, it feels more like a design issue than a coding issue. The `tableOrder` class's purpose is unclear, at least from the name, and it appears to be have more than one job. Those separate jobs are separate classes that interact with your *single* instance of monitoring and checking tables.

Comment: Firstly, please put together a [mre].  There is a lot of irrelevant code here.  Then include the compiler errors you get (in your question, as text). Thx.

Comment: The separation of your code is also not to best practices. Typically, the header only holds declarations. The *.cpp file will hold the implementations. And unless the classes are extremely tightly coupled (yours aren't), each class should have its own header and source file. The most notable exception is templates where you are (more or less) required to put all the code in the header.

Comment: @sweenish thanks for the advice. I will remove the getters and setters in the struct. I was planning on moving all the implementations of the functions from the header file into the cpp file but I usually keep them in the header file until I have checked that everything is working ok.

Comment: @sweenish in regards to the purpose of the TableOrder class I needed another level of abstraction that contains all my meaningful classes and lets them interact with each other. I would then use a single instance in the main file. This was just my idea if you think there is a better way to structure it I would welcome the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to help, hope this is helpful to you.

[here is a discussion of static vector initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701903/initialisation-of-static-vector) and interesting reference [to emphasize c++11 initializer lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) ability to work on all classes:

> C++11 extends initializer-lists, so they can be used for all classes including standard containers like std::vector

Problem statement:

> a class . . . that uses 5 instances of a struct and . . . a static vector to hold them . . . do not want the elements themselves to be static

EDIT: using a class now and the `allTables` vector as a static member of that class.

Expected output is this:

```
./table
1
2
3
4
5
```

The compilation command using `c++11` is this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 table.cpp -o table
```

The header file is `table.h` and simplified to this:

```cpp
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct table {
  unsigned int tableNumber;
};

class Foo {
  public:
    static const vector<struct table *> allTables;
};
```

The program file `table.cpp` is this:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include"table.h"

using namespace std;

struct table table1 = { 1 };
struct table table2 = { 2 };
struct table table3 = { 3 };
struct table table4 = { 4 };
struct table table5 = { 5 };

const vector<struct table *> Foo::allTables = { &table1, &table2, &table3, &table4, &table5 };

int main( )
{
  for ( auto &tbl : Foo::allTables )
  {
    cout << tbl->tableNumber << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! I guess this works because we are creating the instances in a global scope and accessing the memory address so we always use the same ones even from different class instances.

Answer (score 0):

Your `table` is simple Model and `tableOrder` manages list of tables. In such case vector should be private and non static otherwise anyone can push and pop in your static vector breaking all logic of your table order. Construct your `tableOrder` from `vector<tables>` and make all vectors private.